# How to know whether there is zeros for a multi-dimentional complex polynomial function numerically as fast as possible?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials

Recently, I encountered such a problem.
Specifically, for a rather complicated polynomial function with four variables, I need to know if there are zeros in a given complex hypercubic.

For a 2-dimensional case, here is what I think.
In the case $x=x_0 + \alpha \Delta x, y=y_0 + \beta \Delta y$ where $x_0,\Delta x, y_0, \Delta y \in C$ and $0<\alpha ,\beta<1$.
In the complex plane, the function $f(x,y)$ takes values that can be parameterized as a vector field:
$$\vec{v}=(v_x,v_y)$$
$$v_x(\alpha,\beta)=Re[f(x_0 + \alpha \Delta x, y_0 + \beta \Delta y)]$$
$$v_y(\alpha,\beta)=Im[f(x_0+\alpha \Delta x, y_0 + \beta \Delta y)]$$
It looks like this is a continous vector field, so that $|\vec{v}|=0$ corresponds to a sigular.
If the sigular exists and is a polynomial zero, the index will be greater than 0.
Therefore, the phase difference can be computed at small intervals along the boundary and the total phase change can be used to determine if a sigular(s) exists.

It works for many cases but not all, for example:
$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1,x_0=y_0=0,\Delta x=\Delta y=1$$

And this method does not work for four-dimensional functions.
My problem is that for a polynomial $f(x,y,z,w)$, within a hypercubic, i.e.
$$f(x,y,z,w)=\sum c_{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4}x^{n_1}y^{n_2}z^{n_3}w^{n_4}$$,
where $n_i$ are zero or positive integers.
$$\sum n_i<20, \;\;\;c_{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4}\in R$$
$$x=x_0+ \alpha \Delta x, y_0 + \beta \Delta y, z_0 + \rho \Delta z, w_0 + \sigma \Delta w$$, where
$$x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0,\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z,\Delta w \in C$$
$$0< \alpha ,\beta,\rho,\sigma <1$$
Is there a fast way to determine if there is zeros accurately(or almost accurately) numerically?
I don't need to calculate the location of the zeros.

In fact, I need to know the grid-based pixelated distribution of the zeros numerically,

I need your help.
Thank you!

Comment: What is a "sigular"? Is that a singular point? A singularity?

Comment: To clarify, are you only interested in the existence question: answering whether the polynomial HAS zeroes, not what the values of those zeroes are? I am confused because your title suggests you only want to find out if a polynomial HAS zeroes but your question body says "numerically".

Comment: @frogeyepeas I think the sigular of a continous vector field is the location where $|\vec{v}|=0$. And, I only want to know whether there is zeroes in a hypercubic, in fact, I need to know the coarse graining (grid-based) of the distribution of the zeroes (there should be infinitly many zeros). My temporary solution(which I want to improve) is to check whether $\int _{hypercubic} dxyzw 1/f(x,y,z,w)^2$ converges.